# How to convert a fixed length string to multiple columns in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

Using Tableau Desktop 10.x I have a column that contain a fixed length string starting with a letter and followed by 5 numbers.
For example: A12345. I would like to separate this column into two columns, where the first column would have the letter (A) and the second would have the 5 number string (12345). How can this be done in Tableau?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be achieved using this by creating Calculated fields .

click on analysis

1 write the name of the new column

2 in the box write RIGHT

3 choose the function RIGHT

4 add the original column name inside the square brackets, and follow with a comma followed by 1 (for the amount of elements)

[More details](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/calculations_calculatedfields_create.html)

Comment: Using this link, the method is: click on analysis >> write the name of the new column >> in the box write RIGHT >>  choose the function RIGHT >> add the original column name inside the square brackets, and follow with a comma followed by 1 (for the amount of elements)